# how do i fix overlapping numbers in if/else statement?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning javascript, how do i fix the overlap of number in the if/else statement. I want to use 6am to 9am to alert a certain message and i  want to use 5pm to 8pm to alert a different message.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

</script>
<title> Javascript program</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var hour=eval (prompt("What is the current hour?", ""));
if (hour > 6 && hour <=  9){
alert("Breakfast time ");
}
else if (hour => 11 && hour <= 1) {
alert("Time for lunch");
}
else if (hour => 5 && hour <= 8){
alert("Dinner is served");
}
else{
alert("Sorry, you'll have to wait, or go get a snack");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fix your requirements. if 6-9=breakfast and 5-8=dinner then what is 7 supposed to show?

Comment: Use a 24-hour clock, not a 12-hour clock.

Comment: You could use 24 hour time, or ask the user for AM or PM.

Comment: You would need to know if it's AM or PM... Or use 24 hours system

Comment: This is a reasonable question for a beginner, so don't let the downvoters put you off. In case it's useful, you can do `var hour = new Date().getHours();` to get a value between 0 and 23 for the current hour without having to ask the user.

Answer (score 2):

### Description

Switch from 12 hour AM/PM clock to 24 hour clock, which getHours returns by default.

Otherwise, when prompting the user you would need to also have AM/PM as a dropdown.

### JavaScript 24-hour Solution

```js
// Removed prompt in favor of just pulling the hour
//var hour=eval (prompt("What is the current hour?", ""));
var hour = new Date().getHours();

// Changed to 24 hour schedule
if (hour > 6 && hour <=  9){
  console.log("Breakfast time ");
} else if (hour >= 11 && hour <= 13) {
  console.log("Time for lunch");
} else if (hour >= 17 && hour <= 20){
  console.log("Dinner is served");
} else{
  console.log("Sorry, you'll have to wait, or go get a snack");
}
```

### JavaScript 12-hour AM/PM Solution

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6b6gb1p/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type='text' id='hour'/>
      <select id='AMPM'>
          <option value=0>AM</option>
          <option value=12>PM</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id='save'>Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var getMeal = function() {
    var hour = parseInt($('#hour').val());
    var AMPM = parseInt($('#AMPM').val());
    if(hour === 12 && AMPM ===0) {
      hour = 0;
    } else {
      hour += AMPM;
    }

    // Changed to 24 hour schedule
    if (hour > 6 && hour <=  9){
      console.log("Breakfast time ");
    } else if (hour >= 11 && hour <= 13) {
      console.log("Time for lunch");
    } else if (hour >= 17 && hour <= 20){
      console.log("Dinner is served");
    } else{
      console.log("Sorry, you'll have to wait, or go get a snack");
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#save').on('click', getMeal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're getting input from the user, you really don't know what sort of value you are going to get back.

In your code you are making an assumption that the user will use a 12-hour clock.  The problem with using a 12-hour clock is that given a number, for example `7`, it could correspond to `7 am` or `7 pm`.  You as a coder don't know which the user meant, and further to this, you can't tell the difference in your own code either when using integers.

A better strategy would be to use a 24-hour clock.  Given any number between 1 and 24 you know the exact hour of the day it is.

However, you are still left with the problem of not knowing how the user will input the value into the prompt... will they use 12 hr time? give am/pm? or user 24-hour time?  What we can do though is parse the input and only accept certain types of input from the user.  I have written an example parser function with code comments explaining whats going on.

```
function parse_input(input) {
  // these are the variable we will use in the function
  var time, matches, am_or_pm;

  // make sure the input variable has been initialised to a string
  input = input || '';

  // check if the input contains a time and am/pm
  matches = input.match(/^([1-9]|10|11|12)\s*(am|pm)/i);

  // try to get the time from the matches
  if (matches) {
    time = parseInt(matches[1]); // Note: may evaluate to NaN
    am_or_pm = matches[2];
  }

  // if there was no match use the original input.
  time = time || parseInt(input); // Note: may evaluate to NaN

  // adjust to 24 hr time if user entered 'pm'
  // Note: we don't need to do anything if the user enters 'am'
  if (am_or_pm && am_or_pm.toLowerCase() == 'pm') {
    time = time + 12;
  }

  return time;
}
```

Then we can re-write your original code to use the new parser function and 24-hour time:

```
// get the time from the user as you did before
var input = prompt("What is the current hour?", "");

// use the custom parser function to get the hour of day in 24 hr time
var hour = parse_input(input);

// respond to the user based on the given time 
if (hour > 6 && hour <=  9) {
  alert("Breakfast time ");
}
else if (hour >= 11 && hour <= 13) {
  alert("Time for lunch");
}
else if (hour >= 17 && hour <= 20) {
  alert("Dinner is served");
}
else if (isNaN(hour) || hour > 23 || hour < 1) {
  // Let the user know that their input was not valid
  alert("Sorry, you didn't enter a valid time");
}
else {
  alert("Sorry, you'll have to wait, or go get a snack");
}
```

One last thing, I noticed you had the *greater-than-or-equals-to* sign as `=>`.  This actually creates a function in recent versions of Javascript and in the if statement was evaluating to `true`.  The correct symbol to use is `>=`.